# How do I stop all instances of an upstart job

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have the following upstart job which takes arguments to run multiple instances of the same job:

```
instance $ARG1,$ARG2

script
    exec /path/to/executable "$ARG1" "ARG2"
end script
```

Now if I start two instances of my job like this:

```
$ start my-job ARG1=ABCD ARG2=1
my-job (ABCD,1) start/running, process 6242

$ start my-job ARG1=EFGH ARG2=2
my-job (EFGH,2) start/running, process 6254
```

How do I stop all instances of `my-job` in one command, short of doing a grep on `initctl list`, extracting the parameters of running instances of `my-job` and doing a `stop` on each of the instances.

I've tried `stop my-job` and `stop my-job ARG1=\* ARG2=\*`. Both don't work.

Comment: I presume `stop my-job ARG1=EFGH ARG2=2` works, right? I probably doesn't support _windcards_.

Comment: @errordeveloper Yes, that works. But I want to be able to stop all instances of my-job in one shot.

Answer (score 2):

I ended-up doing the following, it works with `[start|stop|restart] svc`.

***scv.conf:***

```
description "An Example Service"
start on networking
stop on runlevel[06]
```

***svc-instance.conf:***

```
instance $ADDR,$PORT
manual
respawn
console log
exec /opt/svc/bin/svc -a $ADDR -p $PORT
```

***start-svc-task.conf:***

```
start on starting svc

task

script
  for a in 10.10.10.1 10.10.10.2 10.10.10.3 10.10.10.4
  do
    for p in 4001 4002 4003 4004
    do status svc-instance ADDR=$a PORT=$p \
      || start svc-instance ADDR=$a PORT=$p \
    done
  done
end script
```

***stop-my-job-task.conf:***

```
start on stopping svc

task

script
  for a in 10.10.10.1 10.10.10.2 10.10.10.3 10.10.10.4
  do
    for p in 2001 2002 2003 2004
    do status svc-instance ADDR=$a PORT=$p \
      && stop svc-instance ADDR=$a PORT=$p \
      || continue
    done
  done
end script
```

See for yourself whether `status || start` and `status && stop || continue` logic is needed in your case. I should note that my original use case required only one instance variable and I haven't tested this with two variable like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use signals. You can stop all of them at once by doing `initctl emit scv-stop`

scv.conf:

```
description "An Example Service Starter"
start on networking
stop on runlevel[06]

for addr in 10.10.10.1 10.10.10.2 10.10.10.3 10.10.10.4;
{
    for port in 4001 4002 4003 4004;
    {
        status svc-n $addr:$port || start svc-n ADDR=$addr PORT=$port
    }
}
script
```

scv-n.conf

```
description "An Example Service Instance"
instance $ADDR:$PORT
stop on runlevel[06] or scv-stop

script
    exec /opt/svc/bin/svc -a $ADDR -p $PORT
end script
```